# Swift draw several paths in loops

Tags: ios, swift, pie-chart

I'm working on changing my previously circlechart, to a donutchart (That can support more than 1 number).

I got all the angle's correct, changed my data to work with an array.

But when I try to draw my paths, it only draws the last one.

Here's an example screenshot of the issue:

[image]

In the above example, it's set to draw this array:

```
cell.circleChart.percentFills = [weight, 10]
```

where weight is the % shown in the label of the circle. So you can see, that it doesn't draw the first angle, but the starting point for the next angle is correct.

Here's the code where I draw my donut chart.

```
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Define the center.
    let center = CGPoint(x:bounds.width/2, y: bounds.height/2)
    
    // Define the radius
    let radius: CGFloat = max(bounds.width, bounds.height)
    
    // Define starting and ending angles
    var startAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat(DegreesToRadians(-90))
    let endAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat(DegreesToRadians(270))
    
    // Set up the full path. (for the default background color)
    var path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
        radius: bounds.width/2 - arcWidth/2,
        startAngle: startAngle,
        endAngle: endAngle,
        clockwise: true)

    // draw the full chart with the background color
    path.lineWidth = arcWidth
    chartColor.setStroke()
    path.stroke()
    
    //calculate the arc for each per percent
    let arcLengthPerPercent = CGFloat(DegreesToRadians(360/100))

    // Temporary var for loop testing
    var i = 0
    
    println("startAngle before loop: \(RadiansToDegrees(Double(startAngle)))")
    
    for percentFill in percentFills {
        
        println("LOOP: \(i)")
        
        if i == 0 {
            fillColor = UIColor.formulaBlueColor()
            println("BLUE")
        } else {
            fillColor = UIColor.formulaGreenColor()
            println("GREEN")
        }
        
        //then multiply out by the actual percent
        let fillEndAngle = arcLengthPerPercent * CGFloat(percentFill) + startAngle
        
        println("fillEndAngle: \(RadiansToDegrees(Double(fillEndAngle)))")
        
        //2 - draw the outer arc
        var fillPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
            radius: bounds.width/2 - arcWidth/2,
            startAngle: startAngle,
            endAngle: fillEndAngle,
            clockwise: true)
        
        progressLine.path = fillPath.CGPath
        progressLine.strokeColor = fillColor.CGColor
        progressLine.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        progressLine.lineWidth = arcWidth
        
        // add the curve to the screen
        self.layer.addSublayer(progressLine)
        
        i++
        startAngle = startAngle+(arcLengthPerPercent * CGFloat(percentFill))
    }
    
}
```

I reckon I'm probably going wrong in the last bit, where I add the progressLine as a subLayer, but I don't know what else I should be doing here instead.

Of course I've tested that if I only have 1 value in the array, it draws that as intended (in the blue color)

Any help getting several paths drawn out, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Grimxn That is the code? addSubLayer is a function in swift, it's not something I made.  https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/addSublayer:

Comment: `progressLine` is undeclared, so your code does not compile. Show your _real_ code, or show _enough_ context so that your code can compile. The question of how and where this thing is declared is _crucial_ to the problem you are having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when I try to draw my paths, it only draws the last one.

The problem is that `progressLine` is declared outside this routine. Therefore you are just adding the *same* path layer over and over as a sublayer - not multiple path sublayers. Therefore it appears only *once* in your interface, containing the path (segment) that you most *recently* assigned to it — the last one in the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thank you matt, this solved my issue!

However completely unrelated to this problem, my animation no longer works. I had a `CABasicAnimation` which was added to the progressLine after the loop. (I tried doing this animation inside the loop, but it doesn't work as intended) I also tried using self.layer instead of progressLine, but that didn't do anything either. How can I animate all the subLayers as one when the progressLines are now inside the loop?